# Syntax Error: import {app, protocol, BrowserWindow} from 'electron'

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I want build Vue Electron project. I tried to output for three platforms but they all have the same error.

Can you help on the subject?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyZsl.png)

Comment: You should follow electron recommendations for importing as CommonJS module: `const { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')`

Comment: node only has experimental support of ES6 import statements, I don't even know whether electron supports it. so yes, use `require` here

Comment: I'll try this and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: I did as you mentioned but now I am getting this error. cannot find module 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib', code: const { createProtocol } = require('vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib')